# Akka Router increment counter on message arrival from routees

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to keep counting on each successful import. But here is a problem - Counter works if the router receives a message from its parent but if I'm trying to send a message from its children it receives it but doesn't update the global variable that is out of the scope. 
 I know it sounds complicated. Let me show you the code.
Here is the router

```
    class Watcher(size: Int) extends Actor { 
      var router = {
        val routees = Vector.fill(size) {
          val w = context.actorOf(
            Props[Worker]
          )
          context.watch(w)
          ActorRefRoutee(w)
        }

        Router(RoundRobinRoutingLogic(), routees)
      }

      var sent = 0

      override def supervisorStrategy(): SupervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 100) {
        case _: DocumentNotFoundException => {
          Resume
        }
        case _: Exception => Escalate
      }

      override def receive: Receive = {
        case container: MessageContainer =>
          router.route(container, sender)
        case Success =>
          sent += 1
        case GetValue =>
          sender ! sent
        case Terminated(a) =>
          router.removeRoutee(a)
          val w = context.actorOf(Props[Worker])
          context.watch(w)
          router = router.addRoutee(w)
        case undef =>
          println(s"${this.getClass} received undefinable message: $undef")
      }
}
```

Here is the worker

```
class Worker() extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  var messages = Seq[MessageContainer]()
  var received = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case container: MessageContainer =>
      try {
        importMessage(container.message, container.repo)
        context.parent ! Success
      } catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          throw e
      }
    case e: Error =>
      log.info(s"Error occurred $e")
      sender ! e
    case undef => println(s"${this.getClass} received undefinable message: $undef")
  }
}
```

So on `supervisor ? GetValue` I get 0 but suppose to have 1000.The strangest thing is that when I debug it with the breakpoint right on the `case Success => ...` the value is incremented every time the new message arrives. But `supervisor ? GetValue` still returns 0.

Let's assume I want to count on `case container: MessageContainer => ...` and it will magically work; I'll get desirable number, but it doesn't show if I actually imported anything. What's going on?

Here is the test case.

```
 @Test
  def testRouter(): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("RouterTestSystem")

//    val serv = AddressFromURIString("akka.tcp://master@host:1334")
    val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props(new Watcher(20)))//.withDeploy(akka.actor.Deploy(scope = RemoteScope(serv))))

    val repo = coreSession.getRepositoryName
    val containers = (0 until num)
      .map(_ => MessageContainer(MessageFactory.generate("/"), repo))

    val watch = Stopwatch.createStarted()
    (0 until num).par
      .foreach( i => {
      supervisor ! containers.apply(i)
    })

    implicit val timeout = Timeout(60 seconds)
    val future = supervisor ? GetValue
    val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Int]

    val speed = result / (watch.elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) / 1000.0)
    println(f"Import speed: $speed%.2f")
    assertEquals(num, result)
  }
```

Can you please explained it in details. Why is it happening? Why only on message received from the children? Another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... there can be many potential problems hidden in the parts of code that you have not shared. But, for the sake of this discussion I will assume that everything else is fine and we will just discuss problems with your shared code.

Now, let me explain a bit about Actors. To put things simply, every actor has a mailbox (where it keeps messages in the sequence they were received) and processes them one by one in the order they were received. Since the mailbox is used like a `Queue` we will refer to it as a Queue in this discussion.

Also... I don't know what this `container.apply(i)` is going to return... so I will refer to the return value of that `container.apply(1)` as `MessageContainer__1`

In your test runner you are first creating an instance of `Watcher`,

```
val supervisor = system.actorOf(Props(new Watcher(20)))
```

Now, lets say that you are sending these `2 messages (num = 2)` to `supervisor`,

So supervisor's mailbox will look something like,

```
Queue(MessageContainer__0, MessageContainer__1)
```

Then you send it another message `GetValue` so the mailbox will look like,

```
Queue(MessageContainer__0, MessageContainer__1, GetValue)
```

Now the actor will process the first message and pass it to the workers, the mail-box will look like,

```
Queue(MessageContainer__1, GetValue)
```

Now even if your worker is ultra-fast and instantaneous in sending the reply the mailbox will look like,

```
Queue(MessageContainer__1, GetValue, Success)
```

And now since your worker super-ultra-fast  and instantaneously replies with a `Success`, the state after passing the second  MessageContainer will look like,

```
Queue(GetValue, Success, Success)
```

And... here is the root of your problem. The `Supervisor` sees the `GetValue` massage before any `Success` messages, no matter how fast your workers are.

And thus it will process `GetValue` and reply with current value of `sent` which is 0.

Comment: So, how can I get the amount of arrived messages. First, that comes to my mind is to create a waiting loop... But, I don't think it will be beautifully done.